# Rolling m die with n sides x times

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception, dice

Okay so I changed my code around and deleted a lot of the unnecessary garbage in it. It works for some numbers but not for others, for example, when I put in 100 rolls/8 sides/3 die it gives me an out of bounds error despite the limits I've set for it. Obviously I've looked over some detail, I'm just not sure what detail it is.

```
public class Ass11f {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EasyReader console = new EasyReader();
        System.out.print("Enter how many times you want to roll the die: "); 
        int numRolls = console.readInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of sides: ");
        int numSides = console.readInt();           
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of die: ");
        int numDie = console.readInt();     
        int[] rollSum = new int[numDie*numSides];

        for (int i = 0; i<numRolls; ++i)
            {
            int rollCounter=0;
            for (int l = 0; l<numDie; ++l){
                rollCounter += ((int)(Math.random()*numSides)+1);
            }
            rollSum[rollCounter]++;
        }     
        for (int m = 2;m<=rollSum.length;++m) System.out.println(m+"'s: "+rollSum[m]+" times, "+((((double)rollSum[m])/numRolls)*100)+"%");                                                   
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `rollSum[rollCounter]++;` supposed to do? Can you [edit] your answer with the actual stack trace?

Comment: @thegrinner It's supposed to increment the element at rollSum's index of rollCounter's value.

Comment: Are you trying to track the number of times a certain value is rolled? Can you clarify the end goal? I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my mind around the purpose of rollSum.

Comment: @thegrinner The program is supposed to as I said roll x die with y sides z times and sum up the totals of all the die per roll and display each sum.

Comment: So each item in rollSum is the combined total for that roll? Or the cumulative sum up to that point? Also, is it the first loop (int i) or second loop (int m) that gives you an exception?

Comment: "The program is supposed to as I said " What are you talking about? You didn't say anything of the kind. You can't assume we've read your previous StackOverflow question!

Comment: So one thing I noticed: your second loop is less than or equal to the array length. Remember arrays are zero indexed, so the element `rollSum[rollSum.length]` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are two base problems:

1. When adding roll totals, you're trying to add the maximum roll in an index one past the end of the array. The easy fix is to simply add 1 to the length of your array.
2. When printing, you cannot access an array using an index equal to the array's length, which is what `m<=rollSum.length` will eventually do. Replace that with `m < rollSum.length` so it stops before the final value.

---

Also, here's some ways to make your array creation a bit clearer:

```
    // The minimum value is always numDie.
    // The maximum is always numDie * numSides
    // There are maximum - minimum + 1 possible values (ie 6 on a d6)
    int maximum = numDie * numSides;
    int minimum = numDie;

    // Remember, index zero is now the minimum roll. 
    // The final index is the maximum roll. So the count at an index is really
    // the count for any roll with value index + minimum
    int[] rollSum = new int[maximum - minimum + 1];
```

I also recommend splitting up that print statement. It's a bit easier to read and debug. Also, you can start at numDie instead of 2 to account for when you have more or less die than 3:

```
    for (int i = numDie; i < rollSum.length; ++i) {
        // Print the first bit, ie "2's: ".
        System.out.print(i + "'s: ");

        // How many times was that value rolled?
        System.out.print(rollSum[i] + " times, ");

        // What percentage is that?
        double percentage = ((double)rollSum[i]) / numRolls * 100;
        System.out.println(percentage + "%");
    }
```